# How do you mark MP3 files so that Windows Phone (Zune software) treats them as Podcasts?

Tags: mp3, windows-phone, zune-software

Exactly what it says in the title.

I ripped my Pimsleur Quick and Simple Spanish CDs to Zune so I could play them on my Windows Phone (had to edit their characteristics to get them all in the same album and in the right order).  So far so good, but they show up in Zune and the phone as Music.  You can't preserve your position in the files when playing them like you can a podcast, but since they are MP3 files it seems to me that there has to be a way to "mark" them as podcasts, so the playback software treats them as such.

When I try to edit the album or the individual files in the Zune software there appears to be no option to have them treated as podcasts.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked this out, finally.  The simplest way to do this turns out to be eye-rollingly simple.  Just use the Zune edit feature to change the Genre to "Podcast".  Open each mp3 in the editor by right-clicking on it, and clicking on Edit.  The Genre dropdown may not have Podcast as one of the options, but it doesn't matter, just type "Podcast" in Genre and click OK.  Done!

At this point you will have to copy or move the file(s) to the folder that Zune is recognizing as the Podcast folder and it will be recognized as such.

Wasn't that easy?

It turns out that there's another way to do this, but you can't do it in the Zune software.  I won't explain it here, and it requires that you use a third-party tag editor, but you can find a description on the [BlueSam Blog](http://blog.bluesam.com/2008/06/hacking-zune-podcast-feature-to-give.html).  A bit more complicated, but it has the additional benefit of making an mp3 appear as a podcast in iTunes (assuming naming the Genre "Podcast" doesn't work in iTunes, something I haven't checked -- I hate iTunes, that's why!).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put this as a comment, but this might be the answer....try changing the file name extension to m4a instead of mp3.  Most audio players recognize m4a as an audiobook format and will remember the bookmark where you left off.

Comment: Nice idea, but it turns out not to work.  If I change the extension to m4a the Zune software still recognizes it as an audio file and will play it as music, but not as a podcast.